# How do I take part of an input as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello people of Stackoverflow, me again. I'm creating a basic Ubuntu terminal emulator as a little mini project in my journey to learn Python.

I need to take part of an input and turn it into a variable, so I can add it to a "command output". Example: If someone puts "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser", the code would be able to pull out "webupd8team", and use that as part of the output, and then pull tor-browser, and use that as part of the output.

I already have a few if/else filters checking for certain commands (Sudo for example) but I can't really go through every single possible option for some things.

```
if "sudo" in originalInput: #Checks to see if "sudo" is in the command input. 
password = input("[sudo] enter password for evan:") #Creating another input if sudo is found in input1


if password == "1qaz2wsx":

  if "cd" in originalInput:
    print("This is here for testing purposes") #Haven't started working on the CD command yet
    CommandPrompt()

  if "add-apt-repository ppa:" in originalInput:
    confirm = input("You are about to add this PPA to your system. Confirm?")
      if confirm == "1":  #Just here to pressing enter will activate ppa_install(), function made to mimic PPA installation
      return True

      else:  
        ppa_install()
        CommandPrompt()
```

I already have this thing set up for the PPA command, but I need to be able to make the code pull the things AFTER sudo/add-apt/whatever and use them in the output.

Comment: Can you show in as little code as possible the exact problem you're having? See how to create a [mcve]. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and keep your arms in the carriage at all times.

Comment: You'll have to do some parsing, and it can involve many `if/else` 'filters' as well as some regular expressions. Either way, it's not so simple.

Comment: Not related to your question but since it looks like you're handling passwords you might want to look at libraries such as `bcrypt`

Comment: @Petar Im making a terminal emulator, not a very complicated one, just a little project to work on as I continue to learn Python. I just wanted to have a password to make it as realistic as possible to a Debian-based Linux terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you need either the **split** method, which splits a string at a given delimiter (space is the default), or the regex package.

In this case, the quick, low-tech way would be to split the string on spaces and pull out "ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser".  Divide that at the colon and slash by whatever string-processing means you choose (find, index, string slice), and there's your desired string.

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) for details.